# Nim must be able to get one character input just like in Bash

Tags: nim-lang

How do Nim get one character input just like in Bash ? :

```sh
read -n1 -p "Enter x to exit " # or 
read -N1 -p "Enter x to exit "
```

Answer (score 4):

Must press enter:

```
stdout.write("Enter x to exit ")
let ch = stdin.readChar()
echo ch
```

Without enter:

```
import terminal
stdout.write("Enter x to exit ")
let ch = getch()
echo ch
```